# SystemVerilog Multi Dimensional enum arrays

Tags: system-verilog

Here is an example how to define 2*N array of enum types {S0,S1,S2,S3}:

```
typedef enum logic [N-1:0][1:0]{S0,S1,S2,S3} state_t; (*)
```

So, each element of the above 2*N array could be either S0 or S1 or S2 or S3.

Let's say I define the {S0,S1,S2,S3} as a separate enum type:

```
typedef enum {S0,S1,S2,S3} st_t;
```

So how now could I rewrite the statement (*)?

Could it be re-written as following?

```
typedef enum st_t [N-1:0][1:0] state_t; (**)
```

Thank you!

Comment: `typedef st_t [N-1:0][1:0] state_t;` should work (no 'enum' in it)

Answer (score 0):

As Serge suggested, probably this could work:

```
typedef enum {S0,S1,S2,S3} st_t;
typedef st_t [N-1:0][1:0] state_t;
```

Apart from that, according to [Enumerations types](http://www.asic-world.com/systemverilog/data_types6.html), you could also do something like this:

```
typedef enum logic [1:0] {S0,S1,S2,S3} st_t_new;
typedef st_t_new [N-1:0] state_t;
```